# problems running brew

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I have a macbook pro running OS X 10.10.1 with home-brew installed, but it is giving me some problems.  When I tried to run brew doctor after having installed it I got the message.

> /usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory.

I tried to delete the home-brew installation with rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup, but it gave me the same error.  Obviously there is something with how brew interacts with Ruby and there is something wrong with the pre-installed Ruby, but I am not sure what or how to fix it.  Does anyone have any thoughts or suggestions?